# How to use same-name global variable if passed as None to a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code:

```
# global variable test
ggg = 1

def AAA(ggg=None):
    if not(ggg):
        global ggg
    print(ggg)

AAA(None) # expect printing 1
AAA(2)    # expect printing 2
```

Produces a syntax error `SyntaxError: name 'ggg' is parameter and global`.

How can I use the same name for the argument and the global variable, and when the argument is passed as `None`, use the value of the global variable instead?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I do not think its allowed to have the same name as a parameter and global, because redefining it as a parameter takes precedence.

Comment: Even if you could get this to work, it isn't a very good idea.  Try to avoid using globals in the first place.  If you need them, considering wrapping this in a class and using class variables.

Comment: It's too late: once `ggg` is a parameter, it implicitly has a value (technically, "binding") in the body of the function. You can't use `global` to reassign (technically "rebind") it.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Do you expect the global ``ggg`` to ever change it's value? Why not just make the default, you know, the default? As in ``def AAA(ggg=1):`` or ``def AAA(ggg=ggg):``.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) dict:

```py
ggg = 1

def AAA(ggg=None):
    # --- Debug prints ---
    print(globals())
    print(locals())
    # --------------------

    if ggg is None:
        ggg = globals()['ggg']
    print(ggg)

AAA(None)
print('-------------------')
AAA(2)
```

The printings of the [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) and [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) dicts help to understand what's going on. The above code will output:

```
{..., 'ggg': 1, 'AAA': <function AAA at 0x000001E5D4ACE0D0>}
{'ggg': None}
1
-------------------
{..., 'ggg': 1, 'AAA': <function AAA at 0x000001E5D4ACE0D0>}
{'ggg': 2}
2
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment, you could create a wrapper class, e.g.:

```
ggg = 1
class AAA:
    ggg = ggg
    
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __call__(self, ggg=None):
        if ggg is None:
            print(self.ggg)
        else:
            print(ggg)

f = AAA()
f(None)
1
f(2)
2
```

Comment: could u do that with function instead of class

Comment: Not that I know of. Although once you've created the class you could then write a function that uses that class, e.g., `def AAAA(ggg=None): return AAA()(ggg)`